# problem with BindingContext in c#

Tags: dataset

I used sqlDataAdapter to fill one of my DataTables in a dataset.
although the count of that table is 2 but the count of bindingContext is zero.
what shoud I do to solve this problem?
here is my code:

```
sqldapT1_AutoRequest.Fill(ds.t1_AutoRequest);

        if(this.BindingContext[ds,"t1_AutoRequest"].Count <= 0)
            return;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the default view for that table have a `RowFilter` set? Try comparing to `ds.t1_AutoRequest.DefaultView.Count`.